# App signing and package installer issue

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

Everyone, i'm facing a few issues when i try to create my app for distribution. i have created every certificate that i need, the Developer an Developer Installer, according to the guide described here developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_to_the_app_store/, everything looks fine, the file generated in the bin/release folder can be executed Without issues, but the file that the installer generate itself fails when it start to use some libraries like SQLite

I get the follow warnings when i build the app

```
Building: Touring (Release)
Detecting code signing identity...
Code Signing Identity: "Developer ID Application: Melvin Starlin Gonzalez Cerda (4J7DT37GUB)"
App ID: "com.starlingonzalez.touring"
Performing main compilation...
Skipping project since output files are up to date
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Extracting embedded content

```
    Merging Mono Runtime into app bundle
    /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mmp -nolink "-minos=10.8" --sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" -o "/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release" -n "Touring.MacOSX" --profile "4.5" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.Core.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.Linq.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.Drawing.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/XamMac.dll" -a "/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.Net.Http.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/System.Core.dll" "/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.MacOSX.exe"
    warning MM2006: Native library 'libfam.so.0.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
    warning MM2006: Native library 'libgamin-1.so.0.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.

warning MM2006: Native library 'libasound.so.2.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
warning MM2006: Native library 'libX11.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
warning MM2006: Native library 'libwinspool.drv.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
warning MM2006: Native library 'libcups.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
warning MM2006: Native library 'libgda-2.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
warning MM2006: Native library 'libodbc32.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.
bundling complete
```

Preparing resources rules

```
Signing native libraries
codesign -v --force --sign "Developer ID Application: Melvin Starlin Gonzalez Cerda (4J7DT37GUB)" "/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.MacOSX.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib"
/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.MacOSX.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib: signed Mach-O thin (i386) [libMonoPosixHelper]

Signing application
codesign -v --force --sign "Developer ID Application: Melvin Starlin Gonzalez Cerda (4J7DT37GUB)" "--resource-rules=/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.MacOSX.app/Contents/ResourceRules.plist" "/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.MacOSX.app"
/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.MacOSX.app: signed bundle with Mach-O thin (i386) [com.starlingonzalez.touring]
```

---------------------- Done ----------------------

```
Build: 0 errors, 8 warnings
```

Also this is my building profile 
http://postimg.org/image/s4m39p1qx/
http://postimg.org/image/kd5db4xll/

Comment: What is "the file that the installer generate itself"? Is it the `.app` application bundle which gets installed in `/Applications`? Are SQLite libraries present in the bundle (when you expand it...they should be somewhere together with Mono dlls)?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @bojan-komazec yes, i'm refering to the .app application, mmm the SQLite library than i'm using actualy is from the Nuget Package itself, so what that package do is that it create a few classes but it doesn't give a dll actually however i expand the content but can't find any sqlite dll.

The app crash (actually close,without saying anything) when it suppose to use the SQLite class

Comment: Ok. So it adds some `.cs` files to your project which are compiled into your `.exe`. If there are no issues with missing dependencies (dlls) then to run your app from command line (I think if you double click `/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` Terminal window shall open and your app will be started from it. You should be able to see `Console.WriteLine` output from your app in the Terminal. Try  to wrap in try-catch block your `Main` and also all event handlers executed in GUI and working threads. Define unhandled exception handler for App domain..

Comment: ...and in catch blocks print exception messages to console. That should help you to see exceptions which would otherwise silently shut down your app with no trace. Also, I doubt that this has anything to do with app/package signing...

Comment: Ok, after i do that i get some messages, like could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json but again, the assembly for this is there, so i don't know if i have to update the mode that the reference and a few more errors related to this, next is the ouput.

Comment: http://codeshare.io/YVpZq here you can check the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of searching, testing, a nutsenses made by me, i finally get to one point that the package that xamarin generate actually don't work for me, so the solution, was given by this blog post maded by Andy Ayre:
http://www.britishideas.com/2011/09/25/creating-package-installers-for-monomac/

Basically what i have to do was compile the project without any package installer and take the .app file generated and put it on packagemaker (can be downloaded from developer.apple.com), the installer file that this generate actually work like a charm, well, on my machine, have to test in another place.

But at least, is something, anyway, I will let you know if it work for me.

Comment: Did the test on another Mac, and works without an issue. Even with PackageMaker i can sign in the installation with my developer installer key