# Missing Libraries on Xamarin.Mac / Monomac

Tags: xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

I have been receiving the following warnings of missing libraries but don't know where to find those, my app randomly crash and i guess is because these warning is someone can point me to a way to reference it correctly i will really appreciate it because i don't know why those libraries are required but appears that Xamarin.Mac need it.

Thanks before all.

warning MM2006: Native library 'libfam.so.0.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. warning MM2006: Native library 'libgamin-1.so.0.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. 
warning MM2006: Native library 'libasound.so.2.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. 
warning MM2006: Native library 'libX11.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. warning MM2006: Native library 'libwinspool.drv.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. 
warning MM2006: Native library 'libcups.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. warning MM2006: Native library 'libgda-2.dylib' was referenced but could not be found. warning MM2006: Native library 'libodbc32.dylib' was referenced but could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible to post some extra info like screenshots, build profile or what your intentions are? I did find a post that seem to point to your problem, go take a look over here ==> [App signing and package installer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713767/app-signing-and-package-installer-issue/24749647#24749647)

Comment: Yes that was another issue i was having, but i still have the same warnings and i think  that those warnings are causing my app to crash randomly